# Cassandra - Understanding Java Heap Behavior (depending on internet connection?)

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra - Understanding Java Heap Behavior (depending on internet connection?)

We are running tests on cassandra 1.2.5. and cannot understand fully the behavior of Java Heap. 
The same test have a different behavior depending on the location within the company network from which it was started. Is it possible that the internet connection has an effect on cassandras Java Heap behavior. It seems for us like decreasing the upload speed has changed the behavior.

Picture taken after a test on the most worst connection of a Java Heap overflow. VPN, low upload speed.
[image]

Picture taken after a test on the best connection.
[image]

We have made a third test with an average connection and have a bahaviour between the both shown o the pictures. WLAN.

Our configuration are:

- We use cassandra 1.2.5 for first doesn't change much the original setting in the cassandra.yaml, except of:

  - key_cache_size_in_mb: 0
  - we just set seeds, listen_address and  rpc_address
- cassandra-sh.env was not changed. So cassandra get nearly ~2G of our 7.9G RAM.

We are using the JDBC driver.

We are just testing with write load.
The test is pushing something about 200 kb per second.
We have no wide rows.
Except of "pretty normal insert", we are updating a variable every write.

Some ideas to understand that issue will really help us...

Comment: I'd start by creating heapdumps for both testcases and look at them with JVisualVM or Eclipse MAT, to see who's responsible for all the extra allocations.

Comment: Don't use external sites to provide information about your question; make your question self contained.

Comment: And don't use pictures to convey essentially textual inforamtion.

Comment: And what do you not understand?

Comment: I don't understand why the same test have a different behavior and the only change is the location from where we are sending the data. One time cassandra ends with a heap overflow, one time a "perfect" garbage collector behavior and from the third location an other garbage collector behavior?